# R. Jeffrey and the Three Prisoners

Tags: soft-question, puzzle, conditional-probability

Here’s something curious, from p. 26 of the estimable Richard Jeffrey’s last, posthumously-published book, *Subjective Probability*:

[image: Scan of student exercise]

The correct (or at least orthodox) answer to this puzzle would be that the new information doesn't change Alice's prospects (see en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Prisoners_problem
or math.stackexchange.com/questions/158641/a-wrong-reasoning-about-conditional-probability).

So … why does Alice make the correct argument to the warden but then update her probabilities based on the wrong argument? Of course one can rationalize Alice's optimistic reaction by retconning her prior expectations about the warden's question-answering methodology, but that's letting the tail wag the dog.

Is this an editor’s mistake, somehow? Or maybe it’s a bit of extremely dry whimsy on Jeffrey’s part—some bait in the water to see which readers will catch on that something isn’t right? No way Jeffrey himself didn’t know the right answer. I’m genuinely “puzzled” by this!

Comment: Presumably she was intentionally lying (in her mind) to the warden to get some information. She is in prison after all!

Comment: That Alice would lie to the warden, I get. But why would Jeffrey so elaborately ask the reader to agree with her that it's a lie ... when in fact it's the truth?

Comment: Well, whether it's the truth or not depends upon the warden's internal algorithm - as the problem shows, regardless of its elaborateness/whimsy ratings.

Comment: So you vote for whimsy. Okay, fair enough.